# DAG backfill competing for insert and delete at same time on SQL table

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to throttle a DAG backfill on certain tasks so if one task in a run is writing to a table another task that is trying to truncate that table has to wait?

I have about ~50 tables in a database I am mirroring to another server.  The process is the same for all 50 tables.  The only difference between DAGS is the stored procedures that get called after the data is staged for processing on the server.  To save a bunch of work I opted to create a DAG factory and parameterize it in a way where each DAG sync's a different table and it's corresponding stored procedure.

The issue I am having is when I backfill too many DAG runs for a single table I get race condition where one execution date is trying to bulk insert into a stage table and another execution date is trying to truncate that same table so it can bulk insert in stage data.  Pooling is not really an option because I would need to create a pool of 1 for each table which doesn't seem like a very good idea, especially if I need to re-deploy the airflow metadata db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting `max_active_runs =1` for this DAG? [Documentation reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#max-active-runs-per-dag).

Also won't it be an option to use separate temp table for each DAG run? It's a common pattern to create resources for single DAG run and then tear them down.